# Macbook pro won't start after update to Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, password, mojave, firmware

I've just updated my 2012 MacBook Pro to macOS Mojave but it won't boot (the caps lock light won't turn on and off.)

So I've try to hold CMD+R during the boot but it asks me for a password, but I don't remember having set a password in the past. Does someone have a solution?
Also I want to know if the password box is in qwerty or azerty (normaly my mac is in azerty.)

Comment: will it start in Safe mode

Comment: Nope it won't boot

Comment: If it literally will not turn on, I'd reset the SMC. Failing that, take it in for service. The Mojave update and the failure happening at the same time were likely coincidence as a software update almost never causes that kind of (hardware) failure.

Comment: you said, it does boot up to the Login password, so what does it do in Safe mode ? and we can not provide you with your password.

Comment: It is the EFI password which is asked indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem, I've simply deleted the content of the folder /Library/Extensions